# save Metadata with image, that is retrieved from html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

what I want to do is to save the image metadata, along with image data, after saving the image using `canvas.toDataUrl('image/jpeg')` so that next time when I load the image, I should have access to that metadata.

consider the image bellow, here I am drawing the objects in canvas, on mouse over it a tooltip is shown with some data. I am trying to figure out a way through which the metadata can be saved along with the image, when the image is loaded again tooltip should work same as earlier.

[image]

while searching for the solution I found that `EXIF` is used to save metadata to image, but found no direct solution for it most of the solution are using `exiftool` or any other third party tools/library.

Comment: Your image, once drawn on the canvas, is not your image anymore. So it is normal that EXIF and all metadatas are gone away. For instance, the camera name is no longer relevant, nor the creation date etc. So indeed, if you want to include some EXIF data yourself, you'd have to add it yourself. There are libs out there that do it. No built in ways though. So if you wanna do it, either use one of these libs, or learn to do what they did (might be faster to learn from them).

Comment: @Kaiido so for EXIF there is no way to do it directly without third party tool, is there any other technique by which i can add metadata to the image, so that the marking made on the image can display the relevant data when user want to view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to save the metadata to the image, found not options from front-end, had to do it from back-end (I used node.js). For that I had to make use of the [`node-exiftool`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-exiftool), required installation of [`exiftool`](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

bellow are steps for adding the metadata to image:

1. upload the image and send the metadata to server.
2. using `node-exiftool's` `.writeMetadata()` method write the metadata to the image.

this is done for writing part.

similarly for reading we can make use of the `node-exiftool's` `.readMetadata()` method.